# Creating a Table in MYSQL Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I am creating a table in MYSQL:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE $URL(Image BLOB,Rating INT(30000),Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Note: $URL is a randomized variable character string

However, nothing is happening. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you check for errors, e.g., `if (!$result) die (mysql_error())`

Answer (score 1):

`Display width out of range for column 'Rating' (max = 255)`

Furthermore let me paste you the definition of the optional `display width`.

> This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces.

**NOTE**:

> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be
>   stored in the column.

All `INT` types will be from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`

Comment: I just checked for an error and it echo'd
 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key. What do I do to fix it?    @tchow002 I fixed that error

Comment: `CREATE TABLE $URL(Image BLOB,Rating INT(255),Id INT KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)`